# Download canvas with image is empty image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on the following demo. Why can I not download the image which is drawn inside the Canvas?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
   context.drawImage(img, 10, 0);
};
img.src = 'https://www.realmadrid.com/img/horizontal_940px/fotomontaje1_20180910050532.jpg';
$("#download").on("click", function(el){
  $('#download').attr('download', "TEasasazzzzSTIMG.jpg");
  setTimeout(function(){ 
  var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
  el.href = image;
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <a id="download"  href="">Download</a>
        <p> </p>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=800 height=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change `el.href = image;` to `window.location.href = image;`

Comment: Thanks Mr Shumar, but still same

Comment: Hmmmm, Try this, I know it seems stupid, but change href attribute in anchor tag to href='#'.  I had some weird issues in past with links because of leaving that empty. Worth a try.